# Javascript highchart passing a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I used the `$.get` to get the value generated in `test2.php`, when I do an `alert(data)` I get the exact value I want, but I don't know what to do to stock the value obtained in the variable `y` :

```
   var series = this.series[0];  
   setInterval(function() {

      $.get('test2.php', function(data) {
         alert(data);
      });

      var y = data;  // NOT WORKING !
      var x = (new Date()).getTime();     

      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    }, 1000);
```

I'm new to JavaScript, so thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses function scope and Ajax is asynchronous, `data` is not in scope in the code you execute after the Ajax call.  Placing the `var y = data;` and subsequent code outside the callback causes it to execute before the response from the server is received.

Adding this code inside the callback will cause it to execute once a response from the server is received and when `data` actually contains the response.

```
   var series = this.series[0];  
   setInterval(function() {

      $.get('test2.php', function(data) {
         alert(data);
         var y = parseInt(data);  // NOT WORKING !
         var x = (new Date()).getTime();     

         series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
      });

    }, 1000);
```

Comment: @Falcon, checkout `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert String to Number

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is probably jQuery AJAX call, where A stands for *Asynchronous*. The order of the events is

1. `$.get` is called, waiting for response and call the second parameter function after the response comes
2. `var y = data;`, but the response setting the data haven't been sent yet (the rest of the function (`setPoint` is processed, too)
3. the response comes from server and sets `data` (too late)

There are two workarounds:

- either put the code into the `$.get` function in the second parameter (as Kevin Bowersocks suggests)
- or do a synchronous call. jQuery won't help you here and I can't recommend it: the browser freezes until the response and if the response is lost, page needs to be reloaded.

  ```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET","test2.php",false); // false = synchronous call
  xhr.send(); // browser freezes until the response, let's hope not for long
  var y = xhr.response; // response is ready here for synchronous calls
  ```